# Maximum speed of time and minimum velocity in space

Tags: general-relativity

**First of all I would like to point out I'm not a physicist, so please don't be too critical about my question.**

The motivation of my question is the thousands videos about the Theory of Relativity and how data can't travel faster than speed of light and how the time slows when object moves faster in space. So I started asking myself what happens when opposite happens. I started looking for answers online but with all my luck I didn't find anything on the topic so as much as my question could be too obvious for a physicist it's not that much for me. So my curiosity prevailed and I decided to ask some questions:

1. What happens when an object achieves truly zero velocity in theory? Does time speed blow to infinity and if not what's the maximum time speed that can be achieved such as speed of light(but for time rate not space)?
2. Can object even achieve zero velocity in theory? If not what's the minimum velocity an object can achieve? Is it possible to know what a minimum velocity could be and if so in theory are there really any observed objects in space with such a property ?
3. If object can travel though time with an infinite speed what properties would it have?
4. What would happen to light if it touches such an object ? Will it react differently(as around black hole) or normally?
5. What would happen if an moving object touches such an object? Will it "explode" in some way?
6. Are my questions closely related to dark matter?

There are lots of questions I have, but those are the ones at which I'm the most curious.

Comment: The thing that slowest moves with respect to you is... you, and everything moving at your speed. Thus, any other moving objects will be seen by you to experience time slower. You are the quickest clock in your reference frame. I am the quickest clock in my reference frame.

Comment: Physics.SE prefers not to have multiple questions in one.  The 6 questions you ask are quite unrelated.  If you really need to, post multiple questions, but I'd recommend doing some research first.  Some like "If an object can travel with infinite speed" have no meaningful answer because relativity states that such things are not physical.  (though you might look up tachyons for a version of that which is at least plausable within the math of GR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer to the questions that my knowledge can answer.

1. Velocity is a relative thing. It depends with what eyes you are looking at it. For example, you are always not moving with respect to your eyes. If I move past you, you could be saying I have non-zero velocity, but I could say the same of you, because for me, it was you who was moving.

Time speed blows up to... well, just what you are experiencing now. I don't know if it feels quick or slow for you, because after all those are just relative concepts. The "speed" of time is relative as well, we only know how much slower a clock runs, but we don't have an absolute measurement for how quick it runs. I can say how many seconds pass for you when a second passes for me, but there is no absolute clock to compare ourselves to.

2. Yes, an object can achieve zero velocity, but it all depends on the reference frame. You are always at zero velocity with respect to yourself.

Again, velocity is relative, you can't measure it in an absolute manner at all. For me, my speed is 0, for you, my speed could be half the speed of light. Who is right? Who is wrong? Neither of us is, it just depends on how you look at the situation.

3. It can't be done, maximum speed of any object in the universe is the speed of causality, c, also known as the speed of light. Theoretical particles with imaginary mass could exist, but they haven't been observed yet, and they would behave in a very odd manner. So for regular matter like we see every day, it can't be done.

(These particles, like somebody has said in the comments of the question, are called tachyons. They are but theoretical as of now.)

4. This question can't be answered because there is no such object. But light goes at the same speed for all reference frames, so you could argue that the same thing would happen than to any other object, though the question itself is senseless.
5. Same as 3 and 4.
6. Not per se. Dark matter is a hypothetical type of matter that has come along to try explain some strange observations that have been made over the years. That is more part of general relativity. While your questions could well fit in general relativity, they are more related to special relativity. The difference between both theories of relativity is the existence of curvature in space-time or lack thereof.

Thus, special relativity, taking into account no curvature of space-time, is mathematically much more simple, nothing tougher than Pythagoras' theorem, though very unintuitive indeed.

Comment: Ok that really triggered other questions but as for now I'm fine with the answer. One thing I didn't get is with q3. You say every object has speed limit of c .I'm assuming you are talking about speed in space.My question is about speed in time. What I meant is when the speed of clock ticking is infinite relative to mine clock ticking for example.

Comment: The slowest a clock can get is that of an object moving at the speed of light. The clock doesn't even tick. Time is undefined for such an object. Time gets slower and slower the faster something is seen to be going. The faster you move with respect to me, the slower your clock will tick with respect to mine.

Comment: I see but you as long as I understand you talk when time is slowing(when speed relative to me is increasing), I'm talking when time is going faster. Infinitely faster(relative to mine)

Comment: Oh you mean that only happens if I go with speed of light?

Comment: The fastest clock is your own clock. All other clocks tick slower that yours.

Comment: I know it would get redundant, but without the word *appear* in this discussion,  we imply what is untrue, that speed, and time intervals, and distance, are all absolute. No, speed or velocity, time, and distance are all relative. so every statement about them, to be technically accurate, should include the word "*appear*".  Velocity can be greater than the speed of light, (c), all the special theory says is that it cannot *appear* to be traveling faster than c to an observer in another frame of reference.  Far enough away, in our expanding universe, objects *are* faster than c (relatively).

Comment: Velocity can be greater than the speed of light... with respect to who? After all, velocity is not absolute, you have said it. I can't have a speed greater than that of the speed of light, because light always goes quicker than me.

Comment: @ChemiCalChems, There is limit to number of characters in comments. Can't add the word Relative to every phrase. But yes, Objects can be traveling faster than c *relative to an observer in another frame*, they simply cannot *appear* to be traveling faster than c.

Comment: @CharlesBretana Are you sure about that? Doesn't relativistic velocity addition prohibit that from happening? If an object is moving 0.8c in one direction and another object is moving at 0.8c in the other direction, with respect to an observer, they won't see each other as moving at 1.6c.

I must be understanding something wrong.

Comment: @ChemiCalChems,  It only prohibits it in calculating the velocity you would *Measure* from one frame of reference to another. A thought experiment: Lorentz also says that distances (parallel to the relative velocity) will be shortened by the same factor, until in the limit, all measured distances will *appear* to be zero length. Well imagine two observers pass you at very high speed near the same time, at right angles to each other. One traveling North and the other East.

Comment: To the northbound one, your length north to south will appear shortened, but to the other your East-West length will be shortened. So what are your "Real" measured dimensions? Both observers can't be right.  Clearly, Special Relativity only applies to perceived or *relative* measurements.

Comment: Also, Hubble's Law says that due to the expansion of the universe, objects in the universe far enough away from us are moving away from us faster than light (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble%27s_law).

Comment: Finally, imagine the two observers in above experiment are traveling opposite to one another at .9 c relative to you.  Clearly, to you, their relative velocity is 1.8c (measure the change in distance they appear to be from each other, divided by time). If they are one light-hour apart right now, How far apart will they be (as measured by you), in 30 minutes?  But to each of them, their velocity relative to the other will be ~ .96c